# Tensorflow Object Detection Api Instance Segmentation takes up entire RAM (32 GB)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm trying to train instance segmentation model using Tensorflow Object Detection API (Mask RCNN) and have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/instance_segmentation.md).

I'm using a pretrained `mask_rcnn_resnet50_atrous_coco` to initialize weights and adapted [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/mask_rcnn_resnet50_atrous_coco.config) sample config file for the said model. I've created my tfrecord files with masks for training and evaluation sets as per [create_coco_tf_record.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_coco_tf_record.py).
I'm able to run the training script successfully but the problem is, apart from GPU memory, it takes up around `45GB` of my `RAM`. Apart from this everything runs fine and I'm able to finish training upto 10k steps after which it decides it needs more RAM and takes up around `60GB` which crashes my system. Same thing happens when I run the evaluation script after training. Following are my system specs:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Tensorflow 1.5.0 (installed via pip as per the docs)
- Python 2.7.12
- CUDA 9 and CuDnn 7
- Gtx 1080 (8 GB)
- 32 GB RAM with 32 GB Swap

I'm not sure why tensorflow needs so much RAM when I'm running the model on GPU. I have only `1 foreground class` and around `500` training samples with up to `50 objects/masks` per image.
Following are some screenshots from `System Monitor` and `nvidia-smi` and my `pipeline_config` file. I'll also upload my script to create tfrecord files if required.
[image]
[image]

Here's my pipeline_config:

```
# Mask R-CNN with Resnet-50 (v1), Atrous version
# Configured for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 300
        max_dimension: 400
      }
    }
    number_of_stages: 3
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet50'
      first_stage_features_stride: 8
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 8
        width_stride: 8
      }
    }
    first_stage_atrous_rate: 2
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: true
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.5
        predict_instance_masks: true
        mask_height: 33
        mask_width: 33
        mask_prediction_conv_depth: 0
        mask_prediction_num_conv_layers: 4
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
        conv_hyperparams {
          op: CONV
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
    second_stage_mask_prediction_loss_weight: 4.0
    second_stage_batch_size: 4
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
          schedule {
            step: 0
            learning_rate: .0003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000003
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/media/ahmed/1A6E52446E5218B9/Projects/TF/MaskRCNN/pretrained_models/mask_rcnn_resnet50_atrous_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 50000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/media/ahmed/1A6E52446E5218B9/Projects/TF/MaskRCNN/train_mask.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/media/ahmed/1A6E52446E5218B9/Projects/TF/label_map.pbtxt"
  load_instance_masks: true
  mask_type: PNG_MASKS
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 200
  num_visualizations : 200
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/media/ahmed/1A6E52446E5218B9/Projects/TF/MaskRCNN/val_mask.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/media/ahmed/1A6E52446E5218B9/Projects/TF/label_map.pbtxt"
  load_instance_masks: true
  mask_type: PNG_MASKS
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

**Update 1:**
I tried running [object_detection_tutorial.ipynb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) on my `frozen_inference_graph`. It runs fine taking 2 GB of my GPU memory as long as I don't invoke the mask output node. I get correct boxes, class and score. When I try to get the output of `detection_masks:0` in `sess.run()`, My 8GB GPU goes out of memory. I tried running the script in CPU mode and found out I'm getting correct masks, my RAM memory usage never goes beyond 8GB (from 2.5GB). This same model takes up my entire GPU along with 45GBs of my RAM while running `train.py` and `eval.py` scripts.

Comment: did you fixed your issue ? can you see mask on train or eval ? i don't see it i don't know what to do i followed all tutorials

Comment: Masks were never the issue. I was able to train the model and generate really good masks, the issue was the memory it takes. Are you trying to visualize masks in tensorboard? I couldn't see train/eval masks on tensorboard as well but I was able to get masks via `sess.run` as we do for boxes and overlaying them on images manually.

Comment: i am able to see the mask but with mask_rcnn_inception_v2 in tensorboard at the evaluation. How many visualization have you configured in eval configuration in pipeline.config ?

Comment: I've posted my pipeline.config above.

Comment: num_examples: 200
  num_visualizations : 200 i think it is to much, when you launch only train have you this issue ? and not tensorboard, only train. i don't know GPU mode but your config files seems to be ok, maybe some optimizations can be done